# Is this person his application approved or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to allow the applicant to check the status of his application if it is approved or not by his ID using laravel 8.

I Wrote code that check if his ID exist? -> show his HR action (status)
And I had this error :

```
Undefined variable: check_stutus (View: 
       C:\Users\dell\Desktop\RUproject\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

in below my code
in blade:

```
<form type="get" action="{{route('check')}}">
    <div class="form-group" id="myP2">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter your National id or Passport</label>
        <p style="visibility: hidden;" id="vis">
            {{$check_stutus->hraction->action}}
        </p>
        <input type="check" name="checkQuery" class="form-control" id="user-email1" placeholder="Enter your National id or Passport">
    </div>
    <button  data-toggle="modall" data-target="#squarespaceModall" onclick="demoVisibility(event)" class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="myP1">Check</button>
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
public function check(){
    $search_text = $_GET['checkQuery'];
    $check_stutus = PersonalInfo::where('nationalIdOrPass', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')->get();
    return view('welcome',compact('check_stutus'));
}
```

Route in web.php

```
Route::get('/check', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@check')->name('check');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .... perhaps you are returning this `welcome` view from more than 1 route?

Comment: may be you have a typo here `$check_stutus` instead of `$check_status`